# UIAlertView remove doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

am trying to show a yes /No alertview and according to the answer do action, but the alertview doesn't disappear

the code I sue

```
UIAlertView *alert ;
- (void)GoOffline:(id)sender {


    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                    message:@"It will take time to download according to connection speed..Do you want to proceed?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [alert removeFromSuperview];

    });
 // Handle yes No code    

}
```

I even tried `[alert removeFromSuperview];` but the alert stuck to the view till the handling of yes/No code done , any idea to hide it immediately

Comment: Does all the code execute on the main thread ?

Comment: No need to code any thing for removing alert view from screen it will automatically removed.

Comment: no need for async dispatch for removing uialertview.

Comment: have u check ur alert view delegate method are called or not, in my knowledge no need of delegate methods

Comment: Having the delegate listed in the header isn't necessary, but is a good practice

Comment: @KudoCC yes , any idea to handle the yes no in another thread

Comment: Because you added this line of code `[alert removeFromSuperview]` in a main queue, I presumed that you have show the alert on another thread which is wrong way to work with uikit.

Comment: Are the Yes or No buttons visually reacting on long press gestures? If not, your AlertView seems to be stuck, because the main thread seems to be blocked. As @Anbu.Karthik said, you do not need to implement any delegate method just to close the UIAlertView. It does this all by itself and informs the delegate afterwards.

Comment: Have you checked whether the UI is blocked by the `UIAlertView` or by the vvvvvvery long task you executed in the `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to hide it programmatically? Without click on Yes or NO? If yes, try with:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

//don't forget to call this in your main thread (dispatch, performOnMainThread, ...)

Comment: I need either with yes or no click to make the alertview disappear

Comment: the UIAlertView disappears automatically whenever you click on YES or NO. You don't have to add delegate to this alert to handle button clicks.

Comment: Maybe, the UIAlertView has been hide by a layer (transparent) so you cannot touch it. DO you receive call-back when you use the delegate clickedButtonAtIndex?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle yes or no as below

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
 if (buttonIndex == 0) 
{
    [alert removeFromSuperView]; //[alertView removeFromSuperView];(Handling NO)
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    [alert removeFromSuperView]; //[alertView removeFromSuperView];(Handling YES)
}

}

Hope it helps you..!
```